# How to get to know whather app has unistalled from Marketplace apps from Admin Panel

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

End user can install my application from Marketplace Apps. But When they uninstall from marketplace app, I didn't get uninstall information and my application starts to get user details from that domain using admin sdk ,It returns '403:Requested domain is not authorized' and then i understand End User has removed app from marketplace apps .So I wanted to capture this uninstallation information so that i can stop tasks related to that domain.

Another thing is If end user install app on particular org unit. I am unable to get that org unit name, path etc. So how can i get that installed org details ? So that it will be easy to get users from that org unit using admin sdk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730966/how-to-get-to-know-that-for-which-org-unit-app-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of a way that it will tell you, but a more long term solution might be to check on it yourself. You can use the Google Apps Marketplace api, https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/, to get information about domains using your app.

You can get customer license info which tells you if the application is licensed or not in the `state` field.
https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense#resource

You could possibly check this once a day for your existing customers to check if they still have it installed, or if they have uninstalled it.